# Deploying Docker Compose to AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose

I've been trying to deploy my Docker Compose file to AWS ECS using Docker Compose CLI.

Steps:

```
docker context create aws myproject
docker context use myproject
docker compose up
```

My result is:

```
FrontendService TaskFailedToStart: CannotPullContainerError: inspect image has been retried 1 time(s): failed to resolve ref "docker.pkg.github.com/org/frontend/frontend:latest@sha256:360461ada5ee15cea9d058280eab4a2558c68cbbdc04fe14eaae789129ddb091": docker.pkg.github.com/org...
```

My Docker Compose File:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: 'docker.pkg.github.com/org/frontend/frontend:latest'
    restart: always
    x-aws-pull_credentials: "arn secret"
    env_file:
      - ../frontend/.env.production
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
```

Output of `docker compose convert`:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  CloudMap:
    Properties:
      Description: Service Map for Docker Compose project docker
      Name: docker.local
      Vpc: vpc-c7823fba
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::PrivateDnsNamespace
  Cluster:
    Properties:
      ClusterName: docker
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: docker
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
  Default3000Ingress:
    Properties:
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      Description: frontend:3000/tcp on default network
      FromPort: 3000
      GroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
      IpProtocol: TCP
      ToPort: 3000
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  DefaultNetwork:
    Properties:
      GroupDescription: docker Security Group for default network
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: docker
      - Key: com.docker.compose.network
        Value: docker_default
      VpcId: vpc-c7823fba
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  DefaultNetworkIngress:
    Properties:
      Description: Allow communication within network default
      GroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
      IpProtocol: "-1"
      SourceSecurityGroupId:
        Ref: DefaultNetwork
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
  FrontendService:
    DependsOn:
    - FrontendTCP3000Listener
    Properties:
      Cluster:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - Cluster
        - Arn
      DeploymentConfiguration:
        MaximumPercent: 200
        MinimumHealthyPercent: 100
      DeploymentController:
        Type: ECS
      DesiredCount: 1
      LaunchType: FARGATE
      LoadBalancers:
      - ContainerName: frontend
        ContainerPort: 3000
        TargetGroupArn:
          Ref: FrontendTCP3000TargetGroup
      NetworkConfiguration:
        AwsvpcConfiguration:
          AssignPublicIp: ENABLED
          SecurityGroups:
          - Ref: DefaultNetwork
          Subnets:
          - subnet-a7d289a9
          - subnet-a56b0484
          - subnet-22df6b13
          - subnet-4c96f72a
          - subnet-3bd2b064
          - subnet-f486b7b9
      PlatformVersion: 1.4.0
      PropagateTags: SERVICE
      SchedulingStrategy: REPLICA
      ServiceRegistries:
      - RegistryArn:
          Fn::GetAtt:
          - FrontendServiceDiscoveryEntry
          - Arn
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: docker
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: frontend
      TaskDefinition:
        Ref: FrontendTaskDefinition
    Type: AWS::ECS::Service
  FrontendServiceDiscoveryEntry:
    Properties:
      Description: '"frontend" service discovery entry in Cloud Map'
      DnsConfig:
        DnsRecords:
        - TTL: 60
          Type: A
        RoutingPolicy: MULTIVALUE
      HealthCheckCustomConfig:
        FailureThreshold: 1
      Name: frontend
      NamespaceId:
        Ref: CloudMap
    Type: AWS::ServiceDiscovery::Service
  FrontendTCP3000Listener:
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
      - ForwardConfig:
          TargetGroups:
          - TargetGroupArn:
              Ref: FrontendTCP3000TargetGroup
        Type: forward
      LoadBalancerArn:
        Ref: LoadBalancer
      Port: 3000
      Protocol: TCP
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  FrontendTCP3000TargetGroup:
    Properties:
      Port: 3000
      Protocol: TCP
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: docker
      TargetType: ip
      VpcId: vpc-c7823fba
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  FrontendTaskDefinition:
    Properties:
      ContainerDefinitions:
      - Command:
        - us-east-1.compute.internal
        - docker.local
        Essential: false
        Image: docker/ecs-searchdomain-sidecar:1.0
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: docker
        Name: Frontend_ResolvConf_InitContainer
      - DependsOn:
        - Condition: SUCCESS
          ContainerName: Frontend_ResolvConf_InitContainer
        Environment:
        - Name: NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL
          Value: '"http://localhost:4000"'
        - Name: NEXT_PUBLIC_SEGMENT_TOKEN
          Value: '"8GVxkwMLOYo5w4XrDwEGtATBaGlUrruH"'
        Essential: true
        Image: docker.pkg.github.com/org/frontend/frontend:latest@sha256:360461ada5ee15cea9d058280eab4a2558c68cbbdc04fe14eaae789129ddb091
        LinuxParameters: {}
        LogConfiguration:
          LogDriver: awslogs
          Options:
            awslogs-group:
              Ref: LogGroup
            awslogs-region:
              Ref: AWS::Region
            awslogs-stream-prefix: docker
        Name: frontend
        PortMappings:
        - ContainerPort: 3000
          HostPort: 3000
          Protocol: tcp
        RepositoryCredentials:
          CredentialsParameter: arn:aws
      Cpu: "256"
      ExecutionRoleArn:
        Ref: FrontendTaskExecutionRole
      Family: docker-frontend
      Memory: "512"
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
      - FARGATE
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
  FrontendTaskExecutionRole:
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
          Condition: {}
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
        Version: 2012-10-17
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly
      Policies:
      - PolicyDocument:
          Statement:
          - Action:
            - secretsmanager:GetSecretValue
            - ssm:GetParameters
            - kms:Decrypt
            Condition: {}
            Effect: Allow
            Principal: {}
            Resource:
            - arn:aws:secretsmanager
        PolicyName: frontendGrantAccessToSecrets
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: docker
      - Key: com.docker.compose.service
        Value: frontend
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
  LoadBalancer:
    Properties:
      LoadBalancerAttributes:
      - Key: load_balancing.cross_zone.enabled
        Value: "true"
      Scheme: internet-facing
      Subnets:
      - subnet-a7d289a9
      - subnet-a56b0484
      - subnet-22df6b13
      - subnet-4c96f72a
      - subnet-3bd2b064
      - subnet-f486b7b9
      Tags:
      - Key: com.docker.compose.project
        Value: docker
      Type: network
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
  LogGroup:
    Properties:
      LogGroupName: /docker-compose/docker
    Type: AWS::Logs::LogGroup
```

How would I get this working?

Extra Questions:

- Is it possible to deploy to EC2 instead of Fargate
- Is it possible to specify the AMI and Type used for the instant

Notes:
I've changed my org name and ARN secret to the values above just to keep them hidden. In my actual file, they are valid.

Links:
https://docs.docker.com/cloud/ecs-integration/

Comment: Yes I have followed the steps from the docs. As you can see when I ran that last command it crashed with the message I posted. What I mean by "How would I get this working?" is how would I get it to deploy without crashing?

Comment: The first thing to try is making sure that the subnets associated with the ECS service have internet access or not. Not sure how experienced you are with AWS however the subnets are of two types, one public and other private. The easiest way to check is, click on all the subnets associated with the ECS service and then click on the route table associated with those subnets. If you see a route like `0.0.0.0 -> igw-*` or `0.0.0.0 -> nat-*`, this means that the subnets have internet connection and ideally your containers should be able to pull the image from Github Packages Docker Registry.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would check that since the way Docker Compose does the deployment is to create a new cluster and if it fails the cluster is deleted. Is there a way to see old clusters/subnets?

Comment: So from the above `docker compose convert` looks like it outputs a CloudFormation template. There are subnet values there - `          - subnet-a7d289a9
          - subnet-a56b0484
          - subnet-22df6b13
          - subnet-4c96f72a
          - subnet-3bd2b064
          - subnet-f486b7b9`
- Try finding out if the subnets have internet access or not by following the steps I mentioned in earlier comment. If they are, then the issue could be something else however this should be the starting point unless you had it working earlier with the same networking setup.

Comment: I just checked and my subnets have a connection.

Comment: Having the same issue: trying to deploy to ECS using docker compose with images hosted at GitHub project's package repository. No luck so far

Comment: Which container registry are you using?